# Behaviour when multiple requests modify the session in Flask

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, session-cookies

Application setup: Flask running in an eventlet WSGI using the default session

On the client side I am using jQuery to send POST requests to the server from within an asynchronous event handler:

```
function set_option(option, value) {
    $.post('/api/options/' + option, {'value': value});
}
$('.option').change(function() {
    var element_id = $(this).prop('id');
    var value = $(this).val();
    set_option(element_id, value);
});
```

On the server side I am adding the option and its value to the Flask session:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session
app = Flask(__name__)
[...]

@app.route('/api/options/<option>', methods=['POST'])
def set_option(option=None):
    if request.method == 'POST' and option is not None:
        option_value = request.form.get('value')
        if option_value is not None:
            session[option] = option_value
```

The above client side event handler can sometimes be called multiple times within a given moment. This appears to cause a race condition with the Flask session cookies. For example, if the event handler gets fired twice from two forced .change() calls on different elements the session then only ends up being modified according to the last POST request.

Let's say there are two elements being changed to the following values:

```
option_one='1234' and option_two='5678'
```

The Flask session already contains the following:

```
{'option_one': '0', 'option_two': '0'}
```

Two separate requests are sent to the Flask server respectively for each option. The first request sets the Flask session to:

```
{'option_one': '1234', 'option_two': '0'}
```

The second request sets the Flask session to:

```
{'option_one':'0', 'option_two': '5678'}
```

The session from the second request ends up replacing the session from the first request thus eliminating the desired value which was stored for option_one.

With this in mind, the session cookies do appear to update appropriately if the event handlers are called with a greater length of time between each call.

Is this behaviour of Flask and its session/cookies management to be expected when requests are made within a couple hundred milliseconds of each other?

Would server-side session management be a solution?

Comment: Well, yes, of course there is a race condition. If you have requests A and B both with the same session cookie being sent to Flask, Flask can't know there are two separate requests with the same session cookie that you wanted to be updated in series. Instead, Flask will update the session cookie with request A, and *separately*, update the session cookie with request B, and the browser will take the cookie value of whatever response arrived last.

Comment: The solution would be to *not store this information in a cookie*. Store only an identifier in the session, and manipulate a server-side data store, based on the identifier, and serialise your manipulations there or otherwise make sure that conflicts are handled there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks... I'm not super familiar with how cookies work, but this confirms my initial thoughts.

Comment: That is probably what I will end up doing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martijn and davidism pointed out, the session behaviour is a race condition and is to be expected.

The solution would be to store such data on the server and ensure modification conflicts are handled appropriately.